# cURL doesn't work after uncommenting in php.ini WAMP

Tags: php

So I tried to make a cURL function get an image from an external link... It, of course, din't work, because php_curl wasn't enabled in WAMP - PHP - PHP extensions. After enabling it - no changes whatsoever. I checked Stack for solution, and I found the most simple way to check if cURL works:

```
<?php  
if(function_exists('curl_exec')){
    echo "Works!";
} else {
    echo "No luck!";
}
?>
```

Although, guess what it echoed...

I have checked the php.ini file for, so to say, "corruption", but the extension was uncommented. The internet says that it is as simple, as checking the php_curl in WAMP, because cURL comes with WAMP installation.

Comment: 1. `phpinfo()` 2. Have you restarted webserver? 3. Have you modified a correct `php.ini`?

Comment: @zerkms 2 - yes, 3 - yes
1 - I've runed it and did a browser search for 'curl_init' - don't know if I did the right thing, but it didn't find anything

Comment: If you are going to retrieve image from exteranl link just use `file_get_contents()` function. No cURL required.

Comment: @s.webbandit is it possible to perform the same functions with `file_get_contents()` as with cURL? if so, I believe I would rather use `file_get_contents()`, because I'm really stuck at receiving the image width and height via cURL in order to crop it into a thumbnail.

Comment: To see if the curl extension is loaded you can also use `echo extension_loaded('curl');`. Did you check if php_curl.dll is on your system and the extension path is defined correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can send GET request and store response content in a variable.

It acts similar to Linux `wget`.

Then you can save response to file like:

```
<?php

// Get response from server (image)
$response = file_get_contents('http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/image-hh-404-vflxxCpNv.png');

// Open file handler for writing 
$f = fopen('file.png', 'w');

// Write response to file   
fwrite($f, response);

// Close file handler 
fclose($f);

?>
```

Image from `http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/image-hh-404-vflxxCpNv.png` would be stored to `file.png` file.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I enter a summary (with the solution) and it doesn't appear here.

Here is the solution I found on the internet:
The php_curl.dll may sometimes be corrupt, or simply not correspond your PHP version. That's why changing the .dll helps.

I can't remember the link to the download, but here is the name of the download file:

> ```
> php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip
> ```

Although I started using `file_get_contents()`, but I see the tendency of cURL usage, so, when I'll get around coding a little bit more, I'll switch to cURL